# How to add a value to an attribute, itemprop?

Tags: html, schema, blogger

```
<div class='bk-left'><span itemprop='name'><b>Author:</b> <span class='product_author'/></span></div>
```

I have this code in my blogger template. The word ( Author: ) shows up in my every post but i don't know how to add a value or name of author in every post. I can't add a single name here as every post has different writer or author. I am confused, can somebody help?

Comment: Well, technically, `itemprop` should be on the element that contains the value for that property. See [MDN's article on `itemprop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemprop). It looks like you should be adding the author's name to the `<span class='product_author'>` element, but that's a guess.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried but i can't figure it out or i am not understanding it.

Comment: I've added the [blogger] tag, so that should help bring people who know about that platform to the question. I would suggest doing some research into how Blogger inserts data into templates like this. Perhaps the [Help Center](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270) would ... help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<data:post.author.name/>` to show the author post's name.

```
<div class='bk-left'><span itemprop='name'><b>Author:</b> <span class='product_author'><data:post.author.name/></span></div>
```

Comment: You came pretty close to what i was asking but not exactly. The above code is right but it shows the author of the website like Admin. Instead i want to mention a separate name in the text or post that appears here. Like i make a post and i say the author of this post is "ABC" & i want this word "ABC" to appear in front of that ( Author: )

Comment: @AnsAhmad In Blogger, you cannot do this using the original tags, the solution is to either make each author as an admin of your blog or do it using JavaScript.